# 403 errors with keycloak API

Tags: realm, keycloak

I'm trying to use the Keycloak API (in node via keycloak-admin library) but I systematically get error 403.

I get successfully an access token via the library; by calling  `/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token` (on master realm) .

When I look inside my token, I seem to have the correct roles to be able to query the users :

```
{ "jti": "xx-..", "exp": 1585561478, "nbf": 0, "iat": 1585561418, "iss": "https://auth-mycompany.com/auth/realms/master", "aud": "mycompany-realm", "sub": "xx-..", "typ": "Bearer", "azp": "admin-cli", "auth_time": 0, "session_state": "xx-..", "acr": "1", "resource_access": { "mycompany-realm": { "roles": [ "view-users", "query-groups", "query-users" ] } }, "scope": "email profile", "email_verified": true, "name": "myname", "preferred_username": "myname", "given_name": "my name", "email": "myemail@mycompany.com" }
```

However , when I do a `GET` on https://auth-mycompany.com/auth/admin/realms/master/users or https://auth-mycompany.com/auth/admin/realms/mycompany/users ; I get 403 errors.

Maybe it's linked with the "aud" of my token ? Why do I get a token with "aud": "mycompany-realm" when I query master realm ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `aud` means audience field of access token so nothing wrong on that.Get the token from `master` realm and fire same query again and see its working or not.

Comment: I thought I had the token from the master realm already ... why do you think it is not a token from the master realm ? On the keycloak logs, I can see the corresponding LOGIN event on the master realm.

Comment: Right Token from the right realm ,How much the life for token?

Comment: the token is one minute long; it is not expired when I call the /users endpoint ..

Comment: So your no any Single rest-api working with this token? If not try with admin-cli tool if you able to create a new Realm or user?

Comment: I initially used an admin user to generate the token and I was getting 403. So I create a new user with the right roles and I am still getting 403. When I log with that new user to the admin interface, I can see that I can only list users so it is not a role issue but more something related to the admin api endpoint.

Comment: If you know 'admin-cli' try this and see if you able to create realm or not? '/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=Test-s id="Test" -s enabled=true` before this command u have to login as a `admin` user

Comment: I am able to login , create realms and even get users via kcadm.sh .

Comment: SO admin-cli command you are running in the same machine where Keycloak running .So now question ,Are you generating Token in Machine where Keycloak running and trying Rest -api from another machine If yes then try to run rest-api from the same machine where Keycloak running.

Comment: I run the commands on the keycloak docker container and I put http://localhost:9991 it's working fine ! but if I put https://auth-mycompany.com instead, it doesn't work... why is that?

Comment: I do realize now that it is because we have set up port restrictions ! https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#admin-endpoints-and-console ..

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realize that this is due to the fact that I have implemented [Port Restriction](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#admin-endpoints-and-console) for admin endpoints. As described in the documentation, all endpoints starting with `/auth/admin` get a `403` response. Instead, these endpoints are accessible via another port (for example `9991`) which is not accessible over the internet.

What I did to fix my issue : because both my **Nodejs** service and my keycloak server are running on the same **kubernetes** cluster, I change the `authUrl` of my keycloak server with its service name http://servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local:9991/auth

Comment: Please write full answer with detail explanation .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I did that now that I have a working solution. Thanks for your help !!